# Hovering effect not working for amcharts5 when fingerprint is enabled in Brave Browser

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, brave, amcharts5

I'm using amcharts5 to create a sunburst chart and I'm facing an issue where only some of the slices of the chart are responding to mouse hover effects. This seems to be happening only when I'm using Brave Browser with fingerprint enabled. Is there any way to apply the hovering effect to all slices of the chart, even if the fingerprint is enabled?

Below is my code snippet to generate sunburst chart:

```
import React, { useRef, useLayoutEffect, useEffect, useState } from "react";

import * as am5 from "@amcharts/amcharts5";
import * as am5hierarchy from "@amcharts/amcharts5/hierarchy";
import am5themes_Animated from "@amcharts/amcharts5/themes/Animated";
import { handleStatusColor } from "../../../../util/functions/handleStatusColor";
import { handleCriticality } from "../../../../util/functions/handleCriticality";

const SunBurstChart = ({ Topics, handleTopicSelected }) => {
  const [chartHeight, setChartHeight] = useState("700px");
  const [leafNodeCount, setLeafNodeCount] = useState(null);
  const [chartDepth, setChartDepth] = useState(1);
  const chartRef = useRef(null);


  const dataFormatter = () => {
    let data = structuredClone(Topics);

    let formattedData;
    formattedData = {
      name: "topic_summary",
      sub_topics: data["topic_summary"],
    };

    //looping through every nested layer
    let leafNodes = 0;

    const formatter = (data, depth = 0) => {
      depth++;
      data.sub_topics.forEach((subtopic) => {
        subtopic.formattedName = subtopic.name

        subtopic.priority = Number(subtopic.priority); //change priority string to number so chart will work

        subtopic.formattedPriority = formatPriority(
          subtopic.scalePriority
        );
        subtopic.formattedState = formatState(
          subtopic.cybersecurity_topic_status.state
        );

        //giving every slice a value of 10 so every slice in the chart has the same width
        if (!subtopic.sub_topics.length) {
          subtopic.value = 10
          leafNodes = leafNodes + 1
        }

        formatter(subtopic, depth);
      });
      return data;
    };
    const formatState = (state) => {
      let status = state?.replace("_", " ");
      let statusValue = status.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + status.slice(1);
      return statusValue;
    }

    const formatPriority = (scalePriority) => {
      let priorityValue = handleCriticality(scalePriority)?.criticality;
      if (priorityValue) return `\n [bold]Priority:[/] ${priorityValue}`;
      return "";
    }

    formatter(formattedData);

    setLeafNodeCount(leafNodes);

    return formattedData;
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    handleChartHeight()
  }, [leafNodeCount])

  const handleChartHeight = () => {

    const interval = 18; // the height to add as leafNodeCount increases
    const initHeight = 600;
    const maxHeight = window.innerWidth * 0.9; // chart does not scale past this point because its circular

    let height = (Math.round(leafNodeCount / 2) * interval) + initHeight;

    if (height > maxHeight) {
      height = maxHeight;
    }

    if (window.innerWidth < height) {
      setChartHeight(window.innerWidth + "px");
    } else {
      setChartHeight(height.toString() + "px");
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("resize", handleChartHeight);
    return () => window.removeEventListener("resize", handleChartHeight);
  });

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    let root = am5.Root.new("sunburstChart");

    const myTheme = am5.Theme.new(root);

    myTheme
      .rule("ColorSet")
      .set("colors", [am5.color(0x5aaa95), am5.color(0x86a873)]);


    root.setThemes([am5themes_Animated.new(root), myTheme]);

    let chart = root.container.children.push(
      am5.Container.new(root, {
        width: am5.percent(100),
        height: am5.percent(100),
        layout: root.verticalLayout,
      })
    );


    let series = chart.children.push(
      am5hierarchy.Sunburst.new(root, {
        topDepth: 1,
        downDepth: 10,
        initialDepth: 10,
        valueField: "value",
        childDataField: "sub_topics",
        innerRadius: am5.percent(20),
      })
    );

    let tooltip = am5.Tooltip.new(root, {
      getFillFromSprite: false,
      autoTextColor: false,
      labelText: "[bold]{name}[/]\n [bold]Status:[/] {formattedState} {formattedPriority}",
    });

    tooltip.get("background").setAll({
      fill: am5.color(0x555555),
    });



    tooltip.label.setAll({
      fill: am5.color(0xffffff)
    });

    series.set("tooltip", tooltip);

    //turns off interaction with the chart
    series.nodes.template.setAll({
      toggleKey: "none",
      cursorOverStyle: "pointer",
    });

    series.slices.template.setAll({
      fillOpacity: 1,
    });

    // Add hover effect
    series.slices.template.events.on("hover", (event) => {
      const slice = event.target;
      if (slice.isActive || slice.isHiding || slice.isShowing) {
        return;
      }
      slice.setState("hover");
    });

    // Remove hover effect
    series.slices.template.events.on("out", (event) => {
      const slice = event.target;
      if (slice.isActive || slice.isHiding || slice.isShowing) {
        return;
      }
      slice.setState("default");
    });

    series.bullets.push(function (root, series, dataItem) {
      let status = dataItem.dataContext?.cybersecurity_topic_status?.state

      if (status && status !== "default") {

        return am5.Bullet.new(root, {
          locationX: 0.5,
          locationY: 0.95,
          sprite: am5.Circle.new(root, {
            radius: 4,
            fill: am5.color(handleStatusColor(status))
          })
        });
      }
    });

    // forces the second layer to have a lower opacity
    series.slices.template.adapters.add("opacity", function (opacity, target) {
      if (target._dataItem._settings.depth > 1) {
        return 0.8;
      }
    });

    series.labels.template.setAll({
      paddingLeft: 20,
      paddingRight: 20,
      oversizedBehavior: "truncate",
      maxWidth: 150,
      text: "{formattedName}"

    });

    series.slices.template.events.on("click", function (e) {
      const dataContext = e.target.dataItem.dataContext;

      handleTopicSelected({
        name: dataContext.name,
        topic_id: dataContext.topic_id,
        topic_status: dataContext.topic_status,
      });
    });

    chartRef.current = series;

    return () => {
      root.dispose();
    };
  }, []);

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    if (Topics) {
      let data = dataFormatter();
      chartRef.current.data.setAll([data]);
      chartRef.current.set("selectedDataItem", chartRef.current.dataItems[0]);
    }
  }, [Topics]);

  return (
    <div>
      <div
        id="sunburstChart"
        style={{ width: "100%", height: chartHeight }}
      ></div>
    </div>
  );
};
export default SunBurstChart;
```

Is there any alternative for enabling hovering effect or do I have to add custom hovering effect to the amcharts?